# mongoose nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

как мне написать вложенный запрос? 
имеется product со схемой

```
{ProductName: "product name", category: "ObjectId(id категории)"}
```

и схема категории

```
{_id: "someObjectId", categoryName: "someCategoryName"}
```

нужно вытащить одним запросом продукты и категорию к которой она относится по id категории

> пример результата

```
{_id: "someObjectId", productName: "product name", category: {_id: "someObjectId", categoryName: "someCategoryName"}}
```

> монго начал учить только недавно. и существует огромная вероятность что сама схема неправильна. поправьте если можно. спасибо

Answer (score 0):

Надо создать ссылку с помощью `new DBRef('category(название коллекции)', ObjectId)`

Вот пример:
https://kuroikaze85.wordpress.com/2010/05/24/mongodb-database-references/

Comment: как всегда создаю вопрос. а через время нахожу решение